# How to find out the SQL used by Spring Data when persisting an entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Let's assume I am using `spring-data-jpa:1.9.4.RELEASE` with Spring `4.2.5.RELEASE` stack, and Hibernate `5.1.0.Final`. When I have a repository like this

```
@Repository
public interface MyObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<MyObject, String> {

}
```

I can persist an entity like this:

```
@Autowired
private MyObjectRepository repository;

public void modifyMyObject(String id) {
    MyObject obj = repository.findOne(id);
    obj.setValue("anotherValue");
    repository.save(obj);
}
```

Now I need to list out all SQL being used by this application.

I have tried to enable `hibernate.show-sql` property, but it seems that only query SQL are logged. No update SQL found.

**How can I know the exact update SQL being used to persist the entity?**

Comment: this is weird. `show-sql` shows all sql being made. inserts and updates too.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a spring-boot project? If so, on your applications.yml you can just change the logging settings for hibernate and it will log queries:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.type: DEBUG
```